# Hello is there are keyboard shortcut for switching to the messages tab?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have looking around by a lot but I did not find anythink. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Given that this about using the SQL Server IDE, and not directly about programming in SQL, I vote to migrate your question to the Super User site.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen really? Superuser for a question about using SSMS??

Comment: @AakashM This site is about programming questions, this is more of an IDE thing, and doesn't really involve any code.

Comment: ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I just asked a similar question on meta, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403813/1690217 and have determined that this question is a good candidate for SO _and_ Superuser, as that is where you go for "how to use software" types of questions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, F6 or Func+F6 (Depends upon Keyboard) is the key for Switch to message Tab

Comment: good job, great work